# Is the Big Bounce Theory valid? If so does that mean all this have happened before?

Tags: cosmology, universe, fate-of-universe

IF the universe is just an infinite loop of events from expanding to contracting does that mean all this has happened before? The initial conditions for the next big bang would (or rather could) be the same as ours which would result everything happening in the exact same way. I could be way off but it's really strange thinking all of this has happened "before" like the time of arrow is somehow looped and we're all living the same life over and over again without even realizing it.

Comment: Probably not, the accelerating expansion of space indicates that there's not enough mass to cause space to contract some time in the future. But even if a Big Bounce happens that doesn't imply that events unfold in the *exact* same way each time.

Comment: Also I don't think there would be time reversal so the arrow isn't looped even in that scenario (not the core of your question but you've mentioned that).

Comment: We just cannot be sure that know about the space-time sufficiently. For example, conformal cyclic cosmology researches (speculatively) the problem beyond confines of “mass”, “energy” and similar concepts based on our limited experience.